# connecting to an existing sqlite db with javascript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I'm trying to build a "bookmark manager" for a browser,it should read data from an existing database on the user's machine.

I tried ST2 and it's proxy,it's explained [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146465-SqliteProxy)  ,but it creates its own database,I can't get it to use an existing database.

I tried the [sencha sqlite proxy](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/using-the-sencha-touch-2-1-sql-proxy/) ,it does the same,it's not even in their documentation
so i'm stuck again.

Is there any way to do this with Sencha?

Another question is : can I do this using just Javascript or jQuerymobile ,or any other library out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect to an existing DB. Think of the security issues if you could.

Edit: is [local-storage](/questions/tagged/local-storage) an option?

Comment: Is is a limitation of the Javascript language or a limitation of the existing browsers ?

Comment: thanks for the reply Jarrod, it will be a part of a browser,that's why i can't depend on any local databases (as my new browser doesn't support it) i'm also forced to use sqlite databases , changing that would be very time consuming.
anyway, i gave up , i'll just create a web service,and put my database on a local server